# Returning pointers from unmanaged to managed code

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I've an unmanaged dll that exports the folowing function:

```
SomeData* test();
```

Let's assume SomeData as:

```
typedef struct _Data Data;  
struct _Data{  
    int a;  
    int b;  
}
```

Now i want to call this function from C# code. I start to define the C# Struture needed to custom marshaling like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
public class SomeData  
{  
    public Int32 a;  
    public Int32 b;  
}
```

And now, i declare the managed function:

```
[DllImport("DynamicLibrary.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]  
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]  
public static extern SomeData test();
```

And in the main function i have:

```
IntPtr ptr = test();
```

Doing this, i get the MarchalDirectiveException: "Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int/UInt must be paired with SysInt or SysUInt)."

I did not allocate the memory for SomeData in C# since i expect this memory is allocated in the C function and them i would use the Marshal.Copy to pass it to the managed memory.

Any ideas? Thanks

------------------------ EDITED AFTER JaredPar ANSWER --------------------

In fact, i committed a mistake when coping the code to my question. The real managed signature  i was using was:

> [DllImport("DynamicLibrary.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
>       [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
>       public static extern IntPtr test();

The JaredPar's answer is still relevant. To get the right behaviour, i have 2 choices:

1) Use the 'public static extern IntPtr test();' (without MarshalAs attribute) signature and then access the returned pointer like JaredPar suggested.

2) Use the 'public static extern SomeData test();' (with MarshalAs attribute) and then simply use SomeData sd = test();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When declaring the managed function you need to match pointer types with reference values or `IntPtr` values.  In this case the LPStruct modifier won't help.  The easiest solution is to convert the return value of test to be an `IntPtr` rather than `SomeData` since the native method is returning a pointer value. You can then write the following wrapper

```
[DllImport("DynamicLibrary.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr test();

public static SomeData testWrapper() {
  var ptr = test();
  try {
    return (SomeData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(SomeData));
  } finally {
    // Free the pointer here if it's allocated memory
  }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in my edit, i made a mistake when i wrote the question. Your answer was helpfull and works but i prefer to use the choice 2) of my edit section. Thanks