# unsafe C#: How can I create an int[] from a pointer to a preexisting memory location?

Tags: c#, unsafe

I am using shared memory for inter-process communication in an unsafe class.
Part of the memory is reserved to hold a fixed array of int.

Basically, I have a method that sets up the shared memory. Something like this:

```
private int* sizePtr;

private ???* arrayPtr;

void SetupMemory(byte *pointerToSharedMem)

{

    this.sizePtr = (int*)pointerToSharedMem;
    pointerToSharedMem += sizeof(int);

    this.arrayPtr = (???*)pointerToSharedMem;
    pointerToSharedMem += sizeof(int) * FixedSizeOfArray;
}
```

How do I need to declare the pointer such that I can use a property

```
public int[] MyArray
{
    get
    {
       return some magic with this.arrayPtr;
    }
}
```

ETA:
If possible, I would like to avoid structs and I definitely want to avoid copying data around. I was hoping for some kind of cast construct to use a pointer to the data in shared memory, such that the data can be used immediately (i.e. without copying).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I can think of another answer.

This may very well get ugly if you don't use it just right, though.

Be careful!

```
public unsafe class UnsafeArray
{
    private readonly int* _start;
    public readonly int Length;

    public UnsafeArray(int* start, int enforceLength = 0)
    {
        this._start = start;
        this.Length = enforceLength > 0 ? enforceLength : int.MaxValue;
    }

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return _start[index]; }
        set
        {
            if (index >= this.Length)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            _start[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspired by this answer - thank you! - I will simply use a Set and a Get method with an index as parameter. It's not as nice a solution as I was hoping for but it is pretty straightforward and it does the trick without copying data around.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you keep the indexer, it acts as Get and Set methods, and saves you some writing, making it even look more like an array.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a pointer, or can you copy the data over?

If that's okay, then check out this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa330463(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It needs to a be a pointer. This array is used very often and copying data around is too much of a penalty (unless, of course, there absolutely is no other way).

Answer (score 0):

In C# 2.0 and above, a `struct` can be declared with an embedded array, in an `unsafe` context:

```
namespace FixedSizeBuffers
{
    internal unsafe struct MyBuffer
    {
        public fixed int fixedBuffer[128];
    }

    internal unsafe class MyClass
    {
        public MyBuffer myBuffer = default(MyBuffer);
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

            unsafe
            {
                // Pin the buffer to a fixed location in memory.
                fixed (int* intPtr = myClass.myBuffer.fixedBuffer)
                {
                    *intPtr = someIntValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: is it possible without using a struct?

Comment: That's a good question.  Probably not; C# needs a managed container to hold the unsafe item.  You can reference that managed container elsewhere in your program without problems, because it *is* a managed container.

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, in your example you have the array pre-declared. In my example, I need to derive the array from a pointer that points to an area in shared memory.

Comment: Then I think you want [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx). Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2338182/102937

Comment: Marshal.PtrToStructure (and similar) allocates an object and then copies data from unmanaged memory into it. I am still hopeful that it can be done without copying data.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of anything better than memcpy.

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memcpy", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern IntPtr memcpy(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, UIntPtr count);

private static unsafe int[] GetArray(int* ptr, uint length)
{
    var ints = new int[length];

    fixed (int* pInts = ints)
    {
        memcpy(new IntPtr(pInts), new IntPtr(ptr), new UIntPtr(length));
    }

    return ints;
}
```