# Unsafe structs in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, unsafe

I wanted to try c#'s unsafe 'feature' by creating simple structs (Vector, Particle).

## **SITUATION**

I have this 2 structs and want to inject position and velocity vectors into my **Particle** struct.
As a test I wanted to print out position's X value, but somehow I'm getting random values.

I have the following code here

**Vector**

```
public readonly struct Vector
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Vector(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

**Particle**

```
public unsafe struct Particle
{
    private Vector* mPosition;
    private Vector* mVelocity;

    public Particle(Vector position, Vector velocity = default)
    {
        mPosition = &position; // here is x 10
        mVelocity = &velocity;
    }

    public int GetPosX()
    {
        return mPosition->X; // but here not
    }
}
```

**Program**

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pos = new Vector(10, 5);
        var obj = new Particle(pos);

        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetPosX()); // prints random value
    }
}
```

## **PROBLEM**

It prints a random value instead of 10.

Comment: Try declaring the `struct` as `unsafe`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey didn't help.

Comment: OK, well `unsafe` doesn't create an entire C environment.  Every time I've used `unsafe`, I've had to "pin" some memory to make it work properly.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866465/102937) for an example.  Notice the use of the keyword `fixed`.

Comment: Another example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11660127

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is there any way to use the fixed keyword with struct. Those examples look a bit messy (I would appreciate if You could provide an example with structs)

Comment: Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#the-fixed-statement

Comment: In your Particle constructor you are taking the address of the argument `position` that lives somewhere on the stack. As soon as the constructor returnes the stack memory will be reused for other method calls like `GetPosX`. That of cause will change the content at that memry address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program {
    static void Main (string [ ] args) {
        unsafe {
            Vector pos = new Vector(10, 5);
            Particle obj = new Particle(&pos);
            // &pos is at position 0xabcdef00 here.
            // obj.mPosition has a different value here. It points to a different address? Or am I misunderstanding something
            Console.WriteLine(obj.GetPosX( ));
        }
    }
}

public struct Vector {
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Vector (int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

public unsafe struct Particle {
    private Vector* mPosition;

    public Particle (Vector *position) {
        mPosition = position; // here is x 10
    }

    public int GetPosX ( ) {
        return mPosition->X; // still 10 here
    }
}
```

This works for me.
Please ... do not ask me why it does. You will notice that I didn't change that much. Just calling Particle with *pos instead of pos. For some reason that fixes the problem. You have to wrap the code with unsafe then and change the constructor for Particle obviously.

I could speculate about why it works, but I'd rather not. Maybe the pointer changes when you pass pos as a parameter for some reason?

Comment: Yeah it's kinda strange, but however I would go with the 1st solution because it allows me to use my particle in safe context.

Comment: @Hrant I wonder if the following addresses it in place of the unsafe in main()     public int GetPosX ( ) { unsafe { return mPosition->X; } }

Answer (score -2):

You could not take the ref with right value.

Create a variable like int posX = 10;

And you can take the reference with variable. You take the compile time reference and read the runtime reference.

Don't use pointers without fixed. C# stack performance ise very good. You dont need this.

Usually pointers use with linking (C/Cpp dynamic library linking etc). If you have large structs (30 bytes and greater) then you can use the ref parameter tag.

Comment: Thanks that helped. The suggested solution is not super clean but it works.